# Get RemovableMedia devices info using C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to get detailed info about all removable media devices such as USB disk,Smartcard reader etc. and integrated devices such as Fingerprint reader,integrated camera etc on my Windows system using C#.
If it can be done through WMI then please tell me detailded approach as I've tried querying "Win32_LogicalDisk" class but that didn't yield much helpful results.
Also there is windows API "DeviceIOControl",can it help me much in this regard?

Comment: I have a USB helper class that will map the logical drives to USB drives and allow you to differentiate which drives are USB drives. But it does NOT contain the detection logic to know when a new USB is inserted, you would have to poll for that.  And I haven't tested it for Fingerprint Readers and the like. Would that be of any use?

Comment: @Gary:It will be helpful because I don't think that there is any unified solution to detect all the hardwares,which I'm talking about,So please share your solution.Actually SmartCardReader device will not appear as USB drive in the explorer so u can't detect it by  USB drive kind of logic.But it will be present in Registry hive under \\Enum\USB.So if I get that information only that where I can get the device in the Registry hive for all such devices that itself will be helpful.For IntegratedCamera and FingerprintReader I want to know the solution in C# as In DeviceIOControl can tell u in C++

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the below class?

```
  System.IO.DriveInfo
```

What detailed information are you looking for in addition to the ones provided by this class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx

You can check other classes in this namespace.

***Edit based on the comment:***

If you want to detect the device at runtime, you may use:

```
ManagementEventWatcher & WqlEventQuery
```

Below is an example:

```
WqlEventQuery _q = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceOperationEvent", "TargetInstance ISA    'Win32_USBControllerDevice' ");
        _q.WithinInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        _usbWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(_q);
        _usbWatcher.EventArrived += new   EventArrivedEventHandler(OnUSBDetectedOrDetached);
        _usbWatcher.Start();
```

and in the event handler:

```
void OnUSBDetectedOrDetached(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject _o = e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"] as ManagementBaseObject;
        if (_o != null)
        {
            using (ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject(_o["Dependent"].ToString()))
            {
                if (mo != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string devId = string.Empty;
                        devId = mo.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID").ToString();
                        if (devId != string.Empty)
                        {
                            Trace.WriteLine("Detected USB Device, DevId: " + devId);
                        }
....
```

Comment: Actually I've checked these classes but they are not totally helpful in detecting the devices I've mentioned in my question....So probably I'm looking for something like DeviceIOControl or WMI or sth like Device Manager to get these devices and get the detailed info on them

Comment: The above code can detect only the USB device at the run time but my objective is different........Whenever I launch my program then all the removable media devices information should be collected and stored in a data structure........so the above code is valid only if I run it as a service but my program will not be running for whole time.......And the DriveInfo class can give you information about USB drives but not SmartCardReader,FingerPrintreader,Integrated Camera etc...So this solution will not help much